# Geometric series - simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to simplify this expression?

$${\sum_{i=1}^n i (1-g(x))^{i-1}} \over {\sum_{i=1}^n (1-g(x))^i} $$

Where $n$ is a positive integer and $g(x)$ is just a linear function.

Using Arithmetic-Geometric Progression I was able to get rid of the sums and get the following expression for the above statement:

$$ {1-ng(x)(1-g(x))^n-(1-g(x))^n}\over{g(x)(1-g(x)-(1-g(x))^{n+1}}$$
With $0<g(x)<1$ and $g'>0$.

But this expression is still not very handy. Is there a way to simplify this fraction even further so I can calculate the sign of the first derivation? Plotting the graph I would say it is increasing all the time for $0<g(x)<1$.

Comment: I have to differentiate the above term and I was hoping to simplify it in advance.

Comment: [See here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/). This might help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was able so modify the first expression.